# Looking for a functional programming pattern to prevent from initializing a module every time

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I currently work on a javascript application which is organized this way:

- I have a `API` module that takes care of all api calls in my application. In order to work properly, it requires a few parameters when it gets initialized, one of which is `hostname`, where `hostname` is the domain to hit the server

Simplified version:

```
export default = {
  hostname: null,

  initialize(hostname) {
    this.hostname = hostname
  }

  call(path) {
    const url = this.hostname + path
    return fetch(url)
  }
}
```

- I have a `Booking` module (actually many more modules) that uses the `API` module to make requests to the server. The module defines functions we can call to access the server.

Simplified version:

```
// booking.js
import Api from './api'

Api.initialize('http://example.com')

export default {
  getBookings () {
    return Api.call('/bookings')
  }
}

// users.js
import Api from './api'

Api.initialize('http://example.com')

export default {
  getUsers () {
    return Api.call('/users')
  }
}
```

The issue I have today is, in every single "sub-module" that uses `Api`, it requires to call `initialize` again and again with the `hostname`...

I don't want to `import` the `hostname` in the `Api` module as it could potentially change, and this library could also be used by other apps. But I would like to avoid to initialize the API module in every single sub-modules.

I've been looking into different patterns with functional programming, factory functions, high order functions etc... but I can't find a right way to achieve what I need to do.

Could you recommend me a nice way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Just use a global var vor your api and initialize it one time only?

Comment: What's wrong with Singleton pattern from OO? It seems to suit your purpose.

Comment: `call(settings, path) { const url = settings.hostname + path; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your solution seems to require the ability of initialising a global service (in this case Api) from other modules only once. The Singleton pattern from OO already does the job. However it is not testable as it would be difficult to isolate the test of each submodules.

One example of a testable and purely functional solution would be to wrap the submodules in a higher order function that takes the api service as parameter.

```
const bookingsApi = (api) => ({
   getBookings() {
     api.call(...)
   }
})
export default bookingsApi
```